# Usage of 'on' or 'in'

Tags: prepositions, usage

I want to know the correct usage.
Among the two sentences which one is correct?

> I want to install Photoshop **on** my computer

or

> I want to install Photoshop **in** my computer.

In which scenarios should we use 'in' and 'on' ?

Comment: In your example, you should use the preposition **on**.

Comment: @CopperKettle what is the difference between using on and in ?

Comment: It's an issue you could write a dissertation about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preposition 'on' is correct.

> I want to install Photoshop ***on*** my computer

We use 'on' for most of communicating devices that *connect*

> *on phone, on computer, on fax, on the Internet...*

However, for computers, remember one thing.

When it is *general* and not so specific about the location, we use 'on'. So, it is *broadly* talking about *being held* by the computer.

> Photoshop is installed *on* the computer
>
> Drive E is *on* the computer

But then when you go **further**, one step further for a specific location, we use ***'in'*** the computer.

> I have MJ's collection **on** my computer **in** Drive D
>
> The scanned documents are ***in*** the My Documents folder
>
> Make your personal folder ***in*** Drive E

You may also use 'in' when referring to an item that has some spacial *boundaries*.

> Type something **in** Microsoft Word 
> Type something **in** the text box

Things without specific boundaries

> Put this photo **on** the desktop

---

As James says in the comment, making folders *on* some drive is also used but it is a bit more *subjective*.

Comment: I don't think I would ever communicate "on fax". I think I'd communicate "by fax"

Comment: I also reckon I'd prefer "Make your personal folder on the E Drive", but I reckon this one is a bit more subjective

Comment: You first get a call *on* fax machine. I was talking in *that* way. @JamesWebster

Comment: And I *buy* your 'drive' comment. Including to make this answer better

Comment: Perhaps because I'm a 90s child and have never actually used a fax machine, but I didn't know they received "calls". (I do realise they use the telephone network, but so did the Internet in the time of dial-up).

Comment: I can see your use of "on" though. e.g. `Could you send that document by fax. It'll come through on my fax machine at work.`

Comment: @MaulikV I think "(I'm) including it to make ...." or "I'm going to include ..." would've been better. I've noticed that you've dropped the objects several times, so maybe they're not typos. It's not part of your answer, but learners on our site would naturally imitate, consciously or not, what we really use. Sorry if this sounds a bit like nitpicking.

Comment: BTW, I think "We use 'on' for most of communicating devices that connect" could be misleading.

Comment: Okay, I take care of this now on. @DamkerngT. And, I *love* being nitpicked. To me, it is the *quickest* way to trigger my learning abilities. I'll keep that comment here as it is by not using my *moderator power*. So that your comment remains valid.

Comment: Would be glad if you provide more than 5 communicating devices where you are not 'on' but something else. I used *most of...* @DamkerngT.

Comment: @MaulikV, I've edited a few items that didn't sound quite right to me (rather than listing them as comments). I don't think I've changed any meanings, but let me know if you disagree.

Comment: It's okay. However, I won't call MS Word a 'concept' (at least not today!) @JamesWebster

Comment: @MaulikV I didn't mean to say that using 'on' for such devices is always incorrect. When I say that it could be misleading I usually mean that the assertion is not always correct or is correct only in some conditions. The problem with this kind of assertion (which is actually quite common in grammar books, not only in our answers) is that the reader may take it as a rule, and always apply it in their writing/speaking. IMHO, this is exactly why a lot of learners have misconceptions and can't master some aspects of the language they've learned.

Comment: A quick counter example: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+contact+you+by+phone%2Cto+contact+you+on+phone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20contact%20you%20by%20phone%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: @DamkerngT., but "contact on **the** phone" has [some purchase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contact+by+phone%2Ccontact+on+phone%2Ccontact+on+the+phone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccontact%20by%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcontact%20by%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BContact%20by%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontact%20on%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes! And that's exactly why prepositions (and articles too, in this case) are tricky!

Answer (score 6):

> In your example, you should use the preposition **on**. – [CopperKettle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2127/copperkettle)

@CopperKettle is correct, you should use "on".

Even though the computer is a box and things *literally* do happen **inside** it, we tend to think of the computer in general in quite an abstract way. Lots of computer terms have parallels with other real-world office items. For example:

- **Desktop** - main area upon which other items are arranged
- **Document** - an item which can be read or written, often has several pages
- **Folder** - a holder which contains documents.
- **(E)mail** - a technique used to send messages to another person.

In this metaphor, the computer itself is probably most similar to a "desk".

Now imagine you want to install a telephone.

With hi-tech, you "install a telephone app **on** your computer"
With lo-tech, you "place a telephone **on** your desk."

Comment: Would you say that a file is *'on the folder'*? As you list it there under the real-world office items? Also, a draft in/on an email?

Comment: A file is always "in" a folder, both in the *real-world* and in the metaphor.* I'm not certain what you mean by the second sentence, but neither option sounds good. Do you mean to say `a draft of an email`

Comment: * with the exception that a real world file *could* be literally placed *on* a folder. But this file wouldn't be considered an element of the folder.

Comment: I think it's rather clear that 'on' vs. 'in' is something someone could really write a dissertation about. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'd consider writing it myself if I had formal higher education in English (I'm bound to make mistakes otherwise), but I might suggest it to some friends who are studying it!